# Using Greek letters for R package documentation with Roxygen

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

Is there any way that I can use Greek letters, specifically delta (∆), in function documentation using Roxygen? I originally used Alt+J (Mac) to produce the delta symbol and it works great on the help pages, but I get an error when I run R CMD check:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character ∆ (U+2206)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

I have tried using `\eqn{\Delta}` but it produces a character that is not the same size or font as the rest of the documentation, which produces a result like this:

[image]

This is my Roxygen code to document my function shown in the above image:

```
#' @encoding UTF-8
#' @description
#' Calculates the difference between two RGB colors using the 1994 definition of 
#' CIELAB \eqn{\Delta}E*. First, the RGB colors are converted to the CIELAB color space 
#' using \code{\link[grDevices]{convertColor}}, then \eqn{\Delta}E* is calculated using  
#' the 1994 definition by the International Commission on Illumination.
```

Is there any way that I can use a delta that is the same size and font as the rest of the text? I was hoping that maybe there would be a tag in Roxygen that allows the documentation of text to be rendered differently for the HTML and PDF versions but can't find anything. I know this is a small error and isn't a huge deal but was wondering if there was some sort of simple fix to it.